# run command until successful n times bash

Tags: bash

I want to run a command n number of times if it returns unsuccessful
I have started with the below loop

```
until find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
do
<something >
done
```

I want to run the about n times before it goes continues to the next file
Not sure how I can continue from here.  I have tried using the return variable $? and looping using this but had no luck
Also how could I use the above loop or what is proposed here to put the output of the find into a variable
thanks

Let me make this abit clearer

so I'm actually running like this with a function

```
fcn () {

    for file
    do
     until md5sum "$file"
        do
        <something >
        done
    done
}
```

Calling with

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P 0 bash -c 'fcn "$@"'
```

So the return value of `md5sum "$file"` is the one I have looked into

Comment: You want `n` successful returns or `n` attempts to get a successful return? You want the attempts per-file or per-entire-find-command? Also you [Don't want to read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) (or `until` in this case).

Comment: so n attempts to get a successful return ... so n attempts at the file before it continues

Comment: You probably aren't interested in the exit status of `find`. `find` will succeed whether or not any of the `md5sum` commands fail.

Comment: A successful return from `md5sum` or from `find` (because as chepner says `find` doesn't generally fail)?

Comment: You also absolutely do not want to run `find` multiple times just to run `md5sum` multiple times.

Comment: Take a step back: how is `md5sum` failing that you need to rerun it multiple times? It must exist, or `find` would not have found it to run `md5sum` on it in the first place.

Comment: Md5sum fails sometimes with i/o errors,  I want to be able to handle this in the script..  My first step is to rerun the failure n times followed by an error file should the file fail after the reruns

Answer (score 2):

```
attempts=0
while ! result=$(find . …) || (( attempts++ > 5 )); do
    …
done
```

The above will set the results of the successful find command into the variable `result`. If attempts exceeds five, then the loop will end, but the value of `result` is unclear if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result of a command in the environment variable `$?`

This variable will hold the value `0` if the last command executed was successful.

My guess would be something like this:

```
while true; do
    $(command)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

Remember that if anything is executed AFTER your command, the value of `$?` will change. So just make sure whenever you execute the command in question here, save `$?` value in another variable or check it immediately.

Comment: Mmm.. the first time through the loop you will check `$?` before you have executed any commands...

Comment: @MarkSetchell true, this would be an issue.

Comment: You do not want to wrap `command` in `$()`. That is incorrect and will cause the shell to try to run the results of `command` *as* a command.